# Joint Probability Mass Function (Coin Tossing)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

So, the question goes like: Let 'A' be a random variable denoting number of heads obtained in first 5 tosses of an unbiased coin, and let 'B' be a r.v. denoting number of heads in remaining 5 tosses.
So, would it's joint pmf be: (5Ci (1/2)^i (1-1/2)^5-i ). (5Cj (1/2)^j (1-1/2)^5-j)
for P(A = i, B = j)

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. One way to think about it is that the first 5 tosses are independent from the last 5 tosses, so $P(A=i, B=j)$ is the same as $P(A=i) P(B=j)$.

Your expression can also be simplified further:
$$\begin{align*}
P(A=i, B=j) &= \binom{5}{i} \left(\frac 1 2\right)^i \left(1-\frac 1 2\right)^{5-i} \binom{5}{j} \left(\frac 1 2\right)^j \left(1-\frac 1 2\right)^{5-j} \\
&= \binom{5}{i} \left(\frac 1 2\right)^i \left(\frac 1 2\right)^{5-i} \binom{5}{j} \left(\frac 1 2\right)^j \left(\frac 1 2\right)^{5-j} \\
&= \binom{5}{i} \binom{5}{j} \left(\frac 1 2\right)^{10}
\end{align*}$$